# Worflow not sending email Sharepoint Foundation 2013

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-email

I have created list workflow.

It trigger on Item created event.

Workflow send email when Item is created.

I have found that status of workflow is completion but still user not get any email .

Please suggest something

### Update

- Im getting this error anytime i open a wokflow in SP designer.
  [image]
  *The list of workflow actions on the server references an assembly that does not exist. Some actions will not be available. he name of the safe assembly? is Microsoft.Office.Workflow.Actions, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture, neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e94249c. Contact the server administrator......*
- EX of one of the workflows
  [image]
  <sub>(source: [juansei.com](https://juansei.com/envios/SPDESIGN_2016-12-26_11-01-15.png))</sub>

> Copy actual element to other list > then send email to ...

Comment: are you sending email to external users , like gmail domain

Comment: Please add screen shots of your workflow so it will easy for us to understand the issue

Comment: im sending to the local users of the Active directory is a company intranet site

Comment: @Phantomtnt - is the outgoing email settings configured in Central admin ?

Comment: i have to validate because the user i have is not local admin, so i cant access to Central admin yet, im on that. At the other hand in other project when i got problems with the email it will show on the workflow status history so thats why it seems weird to me.

Comment: Are you sending to individual user emails or an AD distribution group? If the latter, you need to activate a setting for the group in Exchange to allow receiving emails from non-authenticated senders.